# How to change color (or apply a style) by single click on data grid cell?

Tags: wpf

I want to have the following behavior:

1. Change color (or apply a style) by single click on a data grid cell
2. Switch style back after second click on the cell.

XAML approach is preferable, of course :)

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is an example where we're assuming a read-only cell (otherwise there is a conflict with the click to edit). It also needs a preliminary click to select the cell.

In the XAML resources

```
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="DataGridCell_MouseDown"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

with a code behind handler

```
    private void DataGridCell_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;

        if (cell != null)
        {
            cell.Background = cell.Background.Equals( Brushes.Green) ? Brushes.White : Brushes.Green;
            cell.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        }
    }
```

If you don't like the above constraints, just use the Preview, so that it gets the click before other handlers...

```
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="DataGridCell_MouseDown"/>
```

Anyway background colors can be lost after sorting, so you may need to expand this solution.